# contents of side menu items not showing on click (only the last child content is showing)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Everything is working fine,But the thing is when i click on each menu items, the page just shows the contents of last child.it shows just the value for last Category-> $Category='j_w'.

```
<ul id="menuV2" class="indicator-market">

    <li><a  href="#<?php $Category='cloth'; ?>"   class="action" data-target="tab">Clothing & Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#<?php $Category='elec'; ?>" class="action" data-target="tab">Electronics</a></li>
    <li><a href=#<?php $Category='j_w'; ?>"  class="action"data-target="tab" >Jewelries & Watches</a></li>

</ul>

<script>
    $('.action').click(function () {
       $('#menuV2 a:first').tab('show');
     })
</script>
```

The value pass through the cat.php and it retrieve pictures from database.

```
<ul id="tiles">
    <li><a href="cat.php?Category=<?php echo $Category ; ?>"><img src="cat.php?Category=<?php echo $Category; ?>" width="190" height="158"></a><h5>Title1</h5><p>This is the caption</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML, not the PHP. Also your CSS.

Comment: TBH I’m not quite sure what’s supposed to happen here. Usually if only the last item of a list is utilized for something, you’re facing a scope issue. In your case however, I can’t really tell what the event handler is even *supposed* to do, though. Please explain your JS a bit and mention possible dependencies (e.g. which library supplies `.tab()`?). — In any case you’re missing a quote at the `href` attribute of the last link.

Comment: The last line may be the cause: youre setting variable `$Category = 'j_w'` and if the second code snippet uses the same `$Category` the result would we the one you described.